# Why is "will provide" and "will happen" instead of the simple present in this cookies policy?

Tags: modal-verbs, present-simple

As Cookies policy :

> The following information **WILL PROVIDE** you with an easy to navigate overview of what **WILL HAPPEN** with your personal data when you visit our website. The term "personal data" comprises all data that **CAN BE USED** to personally identify you.

Why "WILL PROVIDE"? Why not "PROVIDE" as a real fact? Why "WILL HAPPEN"? Why not "HAPPEN" as a real fact?

Why CAN BE USED? Why not MAY BE USED or WILL BE USED?

Comment: Or why not IS USED?

Comment: The word ***can*** there is effectively legalese "weaselly words" - some of the data they harvest from you ***IS*** sometimes used to personally identify you (they sell that data to companies who want to know details about ***you*** that will help them sell things to you personally). Other data they hold is ***capable*** of doing the same - but because they care ***so much*** about your privacy, they don't always use all that data as aggressively / intrusively as they ***could***.

Answer (score 2):

Your quote refers to information that *follows*, so as you haven't yet read it, it cannot have yet provided you with anything. In other words, it **WILL** provide you with information **IF** you read it.

The reason for "can" and not "may" is that this is not a disclaimer or warning (as in "shoplifters *may* be prosecuted", or "we *may* use your personal data for marketing purposes") but a *definition* of what constitutes 'personal data'. 'Personal data' is being defined as data which *can* identify you. Can a name and date of birth identify you? Yes it can, so that is personal data.